# Why is $P$ well defined on $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_k}$ and therefore on $\sigma(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_k})$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given an increasing  sequence of finite sigma algebras $\mathcal{F}_n$ on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and a consistent sequence of probabilities $P_n$ such that $P_{n+1}$ restricted to $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the same as $P_n$, there exists a probability $P$ on $\sigma(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_n)$ such that $P\big|_{\mathcal{F}_n}=P_n$

Why is $P$ well defined on $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_k}$
I can easily show finite additivity of $P$ on $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_k$ using consistency above , but how can I show countable additivity?(In general I cannot use a large enough $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that I use the countable additivity of the corresponding $P_m$ which is given to be a probability)

The author of the book I am reading (Ikeda and Watanabe) further claims that we can show that $P$ is indeed a probability measure on $\sigma(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F_k})$ using the Hopf's extension theorem. Can somebody give me a hint or some details?

Comment: An element $A\int \bigcup_k F_k$ must belong to some $F_n$. Therefore $P_n(A)=P_{n+1}(A)=...$. This shows that $P$ is well defined on $A$.

Comment: @YAlexandrov i dont understand your notation

Comment: Ah, I wrote `\int` instead of `\in`

Comment: An element $A\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k$ must belong to some $F_n$. Therefore $P_n(A)=P_{n+1}(A)=...$. This shows that $P$ is well defined. This is how it should have looked.

Comment: Yes ofocurse but that doesnt answer my question where I want to understand what if $\cup A_n \in \cup \mathcal{F}_n$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem

Comment: If you want to ask a question you better ask it explicitly. I don't see it above. Assume that $X=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ and $F_n=\{\emptyset, \{0,1/n,1/(n+1),...\}, \{1\}, \{1/2\}, ..., \{1/(n-1)\}, \text{ and their unions}\}$. Then $\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ doesn't belong to the union of all $F_n$. But notice that there is a $\sigma$ in front of $\cup F_n$.

Comment: @Did I did think about the Kolmogorov extension theorem but I couldn't adapt it to this particular case. :(

Comment: How so? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did In the context of this question we have a consistent family of probabilities $P_n$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_n)$ just like the consistent family of FDD $Q_{\bar{t}}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The kolmogorov extension theorem then assets the existence of a probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}))$ where $\mathcal{B}\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ is the the sigma algebra generated by the cylinder sets. The analougue to this in my case should be  $\sigma(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_n)$ since $\mathcal{F}_n $corresponds

Comment: @Did to $C=\{\omega \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)};(\omega(t_1),\dots,\omega(t_n)) \in A \}$ where $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does this make sense? This is confusing since the author in the book goes ahead and uses the Hopf's extension theorem  and claims that consistency is used only in showing that there exists a probability measure $P$ on $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_n$

Comment: So... KET works, end of story, right?

Comment: @Did Thank you , yes it does . I guess your comment made me think a little bit harder the second time . But what still bothers me is why the author uses the Hopf’s extension theorem !